# Passing Credentials In PowerShell multi line scriptblock

Tags: powershell

I have passed credentials before using a credential parameter in my Scriptblock and passing the value via an argument.  I expect the size of my Scriptblock to grow so I am using a here string to keep it clean then I convert the string into a Scriptblock.  How do I add a credential parameter and argument to my example below.  I know the $credential value I use to get my remote session below has the necessary priveleges to get the file I want as I have tested it on the remote machine.  So if possible I would like to pass this same credential.

```
$user = 'MyDomain\username' 
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'mypassword' -asplaintext -force
$credential = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user, $password

try {
    $s = New-PSSession -ComputerName MyRemoteComputer -Credential $credential

    $remoteCommand = @" 
        New-PSDrive -Name 'P' -PSProvider 'FileSystem' -Root '\\main-server\Folders\DevOps\Projetcs\Juniper'
           Get-Item -Path P:\V1.6\InstallFiles\Install.bat 
"@
    $scriptBlock = [Scriptblock]::Create($remoteCommand)
    $status = Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock 

    Write-Host $status
    Exit-PSSession -Session $s
}
catch {

  #TODO Add exception handling
}
```

Comment: What you're trying here won't work, or won't work easily.  It's the [double hop problem.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/setup/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-6)

Comment: @BaconBits Your comment might be extremely helpful.  If it is, in fact, the double hop problem I have worked around that before.  I'll report back and let you know if enabling credssp fixes the issue. :)

Comment: The only other thing I see is that you don't need ScriptBlock.Create().  Just create a script block like so:  `$ScriptBlock = { Write-Host 'Hello world' }`  And then call it with `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock`.

Comment: Also, beware of CredSSP's security impact!  It's one of the easiest ways to circumvent the problem, but it makes you more vulnerable to credential theft.

Comment: I will add Disable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client to my script when the work is finished.